# Template Navbar Hover dropdowm

Tags: html, css, navbar

Can someone tell me how they have created this navbar in the given template.

http://templates.entheosweb.com/template_number/live_demo.asp?TemplateID=38947

I just need to know how they did the drop down for links like 'Services'.

Thanks

Comment: that menu is done using superfish menu..

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use lists under lists to make the dropdown and then, with jquery show and hide the element...

```
<ul class="menu">
<li>Main
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>Sub</li>
        <li>Sub</li>
        <li>Sub</li>
        <li>Sub</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

and then, with CSS, hide the drop down menu...

```
.dropdown {
  display: none;
}
```

using a little bit of jquery and the function `.slideToggle()` when trigger a "click" to show the sub menu.

```
$('.menu').children('li').on('click', function() {
   $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('slow'); 
});
```

hope this help you...

here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GxB6q/)